# how to integrate facebook "App-to-User Notifications" into wordpress post comments

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, notifications

Facebook re activated the [App-to-User Notifications](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications) again.

i am trying to find a way to make my wordpress website send a notification to my user when someone writes a comment to his post on my website.

my users are registered using their Facebook accounts.

Facebook just mentioned that Apps can generate notifications by issuing a HTTP POST request to the /user_id/notifications using

```
POST /{recipient_userid}/notifications?access_token=... &template=...&href=...
```

How to integrate this API call into wordpress?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, your question is too wide because it seems like you are asking the whole guide on how to implement this API call in Wordpress.

So let me just give you the direction:

1. Get the Facebook PHP SDK from git here: [Facebook SDK for PHP (v5)](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk)
2. Implement Wordpress HOOK either in your theme or in the plugin, so that you can handle things when comment is posted. [Wordpress Comment Post Hook Document](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_post/)

So in Wordpress side, you will need to create a function which takes the `facebook user token` who made a post, make an API call, and then link this function to `comment_post` hook.

Hope this will give you an idea.